# Is there a schsim between classical logic and categorical logic?

Tags: logic, soft-question, foundations

I've been trying to learn a little bit more about the foundations of mathematics, and it has strike me that there seems to be two competing points of view about what the foundations should be. While classical logic seems to focus on a set theory like ZFC or an extension of it, in categorical logic you will use something like ETCS. Are developments of the two points of view mostly parallel? Is there a dominant point of view at the moment? Is there some kind of schism between proponents of the two points of view? Or will they mostly go to the same logic conferences and hang around together?

Comment: Do you have a link for ETCS?

Comment: Here is one: [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS).

Comment: My knowledge about category theory is mostly limited to its basics and I have only thought about possible foundations via extensions of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ (so take this comment with a grain of salt), but recently I was asked to give a short talk about possible foundations of category theory via Grothendieck's Axiom and - in preparation to that - I took a quick look at some alternatives. The general tone suggested that the mainstream foundations are compatible in many ways and that 'natural' categories behave as expected in basically all of them.

Comment: What was interesting to me however - from a set theorist's point of view - is that these foundations are not interchangeable and do come with their differences. We may for example add some (anti-) large cardinal hypotheses that change the kind of categories we can produce. It is then at least feasible that there are then interesting (in the sense that they are interesting to category theorists and not only set theorists) theorems about categories that depend on such assumptions.